# Can I control where Eclipse gets its pop-up javadoc from?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I have two Eclipse java projects that contain different versions of the same classes (don't ask :-)). The classes are in the same packages in each project. What I would like is that when I hover over a method definition in one project the pop-up javadoc I see is the javadoc from the version of the method in the other project.

I can't see any way in Eclipse to control this. I can configure the project's "external javadoc" location (that gets shown when you shift-F2) and that works fine. But it doesn't seem to affect the pop-up javadoc.

Is there any way of achieving what I want?

More explanation: The code is a library. One of the projects holds the library api that clients compile against - all the methods just throw an exception. The other project holds the library implementation, which clients never see. The api is documented with javadoc in the api project and I don't want to duplicate those comments in the implementation. But it would be handy to see those comments when editing the implementation.

Comment: Sounds like bug in eclipse...

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think the javadoc is taken directly from the jdk, so an explanation might be that the 2 projects use 2 different jdk?

Comment: To be clear: it's the javadoc for *my* classes I'm concerned about, not the javadoc for the jdk. Thanks.

Comment: When you set up the build path for a project you can specify for each resource where to get the javadoc; I'm not 100% sure though that it can be done for other projects in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like is that when I hover over a method definition in one
>   project the pop-up javadoc I see is the javadoc from the version of
>   the method in the other project.

That looks wrong. You want to see the Javadoc from the other project but the actual method invocation will continue to refer to the method from the same project.

To see the Javadoc from another project you need to make sure that your method invocation also refers to the method declaration in the other project.

EDIT:

> I don't want to duplicate those comments in the implementation

You can use '@see ' tags in the javadoc. That has the effect of just picking the javadoc from the referred method in the @see tag.

Comment: Please see the extra information I have added to the question. Thanks.